# Is the use of a type where its range-restricted subtype is expected considered correct in Ada?

Tags: range, ada, subtype, subtyping

According to slide 28 of
https://github.com/AdaCoreU/Courses/blob/master/lectures/03_Programming_in_the_Large/02_Type_Safety/slides/Strong_Typing.ppt?raw=true
the below code is correct, because
"T is a subtype of Integer. Therefore, V1 and V2 are of the same type"

```
procedure weirdada is
  subtype T is Integer range 1 .. Integer'Last;
  V1 : Integer := 0;
  V2 : T := V1;
begin
  null;
end;
```

But what is the purpose of a range declaration if I am allowed violate it?
My thinking seems correct, since there is a warning at compiletime,
and an exception at runtime.

```
$ ./gnat-gpl-2014-x86-linux-bin/bin/gnatmake weirdada.adb
gcc -c weirdada.adb
weirdada.adb:4:19: warning: value not in range of type "T" defined at line 2
weirdada.adb:4:19: warning: "Constraint_Error" will be raised at run time
gnatbind -x weirdada.ali
gnatlink weirdada.ali

$ ./weirdada
raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : weirdada.adb:4 range check failed
```

Is the slide incorrect, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: But see slide 7. By the way, it looks as though you haven’t completed the GNAT installation properly: you should run `doinstall`.

Comment: Are you thinking that the compiler should catch the problem at compile time?  Keep in mind that something like `V2 : T := V1` can't always be caught at compile time, if `V1` isn't a known value.  Trying to write language rules so that compile errors occur if the compiler "can" determine that the value will always be out of range, would be extremely difficult and not all that useful.  "Value following" is hard.  While you can tell right away that the assignment will be out of range, it's actually a very tough problem for a compiler.

Comment: @ajb The compiler recognizes it! That is not what I wonder about, but whether the slide is correct or not, and whether there is some practical application of allowing (just warning instead of error) the assignment from a range to a variable declared to be its subrange.

Comment: you could pass -gnatwe to gnatmake and it should fail at compilation.

Comment: The code is indeed legal. There’s discussion in the [Ada 83 Rationale, section 4.4](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83rat/html/ratl-04-04.html#4.4).

Answer (score 3):

Ada distinguishes between types and subtypes.  Types are separate spaces of values.  Subtypes are compatible subsets of a given type.

As it isn't generally possible to make a compile-time check of a conversion between different subtypes of a type (technically both `T` and `Integer` are subtypes), all such conversions are considered legal at compile-time, but may of course be fail at run-time, if the actual value doesn't fit in the target subtype.

So yes, you may have missed the difference between types and subtypes.